# 1062 Duplicate entry '234' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am importing posts from drupal to WP and I want to have categories and tags too when I run the script it imports all the things but  not categories and tags and I get this error:

```
Query:

INSERT INTO wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent)
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.tid, d.tid 'term_id', 'post_tag', d.description 'description',
    h.parent 'parent'
FROM drupal.term_data d
INNER JOIN drupal.term_hierarchy h USING(tid)
INNER JOIN drupal.term_node n USING(tid)
WHERE (1);
```

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '234' for key 'PRIMARY'

I dropped my node_term table but it didn't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=1062+Duplicate+entry

Comment: It looks like maybe a unique constraint in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table is being violated.  Check your data and the table definition.

Comment: I checked many other questions but I still don't get it. I tried to reupload the database and that table but it didnt help

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its empty nothing is there

Comment: @Vidal No, the issue is not that this table is empty to begin with, it's that you are inserting data which violates a unique constraint.

Comment: i got it. any help I can fix this? actually I m trying to import categories and assign them automatically with the posts. I have exported data is csv, .sql and xml I even imported it in posts categories but the list is huge and I want them to assign automatically. is there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly inserting a value that is already in the table -- or, your query has the value "234" twice for the primary key.

You can check for the second condition by doing a separate subquery:

```
select pk, count(*)
from (<your select here>) t
group by pk
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can fix both problems with `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  I prefer the latter:

```
INSERT INTO wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy (term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent)
    SELECT DISTINCT d.tid, d.tid, 'post_tag', d.description,h.parent
    FROM drupal.term_data d INNER JOIN
         drupal.term_hierarchy h USING( tid) INNER JOIN
         drupal.term_node n USING( tid)
    WHERE (1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE term_taxonomy_id = VALUES(term_taxonomy_id);
```